# Exclude resources from exported war file

Tags: java, eclipse, war

I would like to exclude a couple of .properties files which are in a package of src/main/resources from exported WAR files of Eclipse.

I am trying to exclude them with the "Source" tab of Java Build Path, adding the package as a Excluded, but it seems that it doesn't work with files (but it is working with classes) because they are all included in the generated WAR file. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see the image, but src/main/resources indicates that you have a Maven project. Did you configure the war plugin in the pom.xml file as described e.g. here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html?

Comment: @hammerfest it is a gradle project. Anyway, I am exporting the WAR file witth Eclipse. And all this Eclipse excluding config work with classes, but why not with .properties files?